# What is the procedure for replacing the battery on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, battery

What is the procedure for replacing the battery on an iPhone?

Answer (score 7):

[iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com) has excellent text and video guides for replacing the battery on all models of the iPhone.  Here's their [iPhone 4 battery replacement guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-iPhone-4-Battery/3141/1).

Comment: I have successfully replaced my iPhone 5 screen using this guide a few months ago. (The procedure is very similar to replacing the battery; obviously both require opening the phone.)

Comment: Protip: I found I needed a much stronger suction cup than the simple one included by iFixit. I used one from a vehicle windshield GPS-mount that has a plastic lever-clamp to really make it suction down hard on the glass. That was perfect and popped the screen loose about 10 times easier!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep your warranty alive at all, take it to your local Apple store or authorised repair centre and ask for the service. Any other action may void your warranty.

Comment: *IF* it's within warranty - it is *very* helpful. Your battery will be covered. They'll replace the phone.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which one you have. I have replaced LCDs and glass screens on the 3G before. Following tutorials at [Repairs Universe](http://www.repairsuniverse.com/) is really helpful. They have videos and detailed instructions. [Here's](http://zedomax.com/blog/2010/03/13/iphone-diy-how-to-replace-iphone-battery/) a tutorial. I haven't looked at it, but it popped up by Googling "replace iPhone battery."

Hope this helps!
Thomas